# appending json return data into html with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

What is the proper way to append JSON return data into an img src tag?

**HTML**

---

```
<a class="bigImg rght" style="width:258px;">
<img src="" alt="Slide" width="298" height="224" /></a>
```

### Ajax Function Call:

```
   var parent_img = $(this).parent().find('img');

    success : function(data) {

    if (data.error === false)
    {
    parent_img.attr("src","http://www.test.com/index/"
    +text(data.client_id)+"/"+text(data.client_name)"").fadeIn(1000);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `""` from `text(data.client_name)"")` and it should be fine.